# Python Pydantic Get JSON Regardless of Validation

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a class in Pydantic that fails validation. I would like to fetch the JSON regardless of failure. Any ideas?

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, ValidationError

class Model(BaseModel):
    a: float = Field(ge=1.0)

try:
    m = Model(a=0.5)
    print(m.json())
except ValidationError as e:
    data = e.data()  # fake method, would return '{"a": 0.5}
    data['errors'] = e.json()
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict manually and then pass it further

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, ValidationError

class Model(BaseModel):
    a: float = Field(ge=1.0)

try:
    d = {'a': 0.5}
    m = Model.parse_obj(d)
    print(m.json())
except ValidationError as e:
    d['errors'] = e.json()
    print(d)
```